# Как вывести картинку Django?

Tags: django, django-model, django-template

Надо вывести картинку на страницу но почему не работает

Модели

```
class Part(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField('Производитель', max_length=100)
    number = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    analog = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='AnalogParts')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.brand + " " + self.number + " " + self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Запчасть'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Запчасти'

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Part, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.number
```

Шаблон HTML

```
{% for el in searchPart %}
<div class="card col-xl-8" style="margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="mb-2">
        <p class="h4 text-dark">{{ el.brand }} {{ el.number }}</p>
    </div>
    <p class="text-muted mt-2 mb-2">
      Наименование запчасти: {{ el.name }}
      <img src={{ el.imgage.url }} width="350" height="250">
      <br>
```

Comment: У Вас в шаблоне imgage, а в моделях с картинкой ForeignKey в PostImage, еще  и называется images

Comment: тоесть получается надо вот так в шаблоне написать

      <img src={{ el.images.url }} width="350" height="250">